# Properties on CSS overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have 2 questions or rather clarifications I need related to CSS overflow property..It is said that

> Boxes with an overflow value other than visible will expand vertically
>   to enclose any floated descendant boxes.

Also regarding margins, it is said that

> Margins will never collapse for a box with an overflow value other
>   than visible.

### Could you please explain these 2 points with any practical use of the same..It would be great if you could include any example to demonstrate the same.

**My demos on this;**

http://jsfiddle.net/emeRJ/13/

http://jsfiddle.net/emeRJ/12/

Comment: I have already gone through that link...But it does not have an example demonstrating the point..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) if you have an element that has overflow set to something different than "visible", the height of the element will be expand according to the float elements inside.

check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/emeRJ/3/

since i haven't defined the `height` for the box, it will be expanded by the floating blocks inside. Only because overflow is not "visible".. So if you set the overflow to visible, the box wont consider the floating elements and the height of the box will be 0 (in the example, if you change the overflow to visible you wont see the gray background)

So there are different behaviors when using overflow, float and height (or width) together.
`Overflow` will tell the browser what to do with the content that can't fit in the box (if you have defined the dimensions of the box), `Float` will put elements next to each other respecting the dimensions of the parent element, and height and width will delimit the visible area

[ even more complicated ] in the example, when the overflow to visible, you could still force the box to expand if you add a [clearer element](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) inside:
http://jsfiddle.net/emeRJ/4/

2) for the second, you should really read the [link](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins) given by @feeela about collapsing margins... =P

Hope this helps

Comment: Mind blowing answer to say the least...I had a couple of things though...First something which I learnt new (but even find a bit tricky to understand) that if overflow is visible, the box wont consider the floating elements (though there is the "clearer" workaround)
Second Do floated elements always respect the dimensions of the parent element ? I mean is there any exception to that rule ?

An EXCELLENT ANSWER in any case...You deserve a 1000+ vote on thos one..

Comment: to your 2nd question.. float element will "try" to respect the dimensions of the parent (if you set them) http://jsfiddle.net/emeRJ/5/ that's why you need to use `overflow` to tell the browser what to do when the content is too big for the box

Comment: Just one more question before i close this...i see that the practical example of float respecting parent element dimensions is for creating flexible or fluid layouts...Is there some other way by which you think we can implement fluid layouts ? I am referring to a layout similar to http://matthewjamestaylor.com/demos/ipad-css-layout/

Comment: hmm i'm not really sure if the example you gave could be considered as fluid layout (im really no expert in that) I taught that fluid layout was referred to using percentages in the dimensions of the elements, so it would adapt to almost any screen resolution without changing the general structure.. anyway the technique involves using percentages and (maybe?) min-height and max-height... that's all I know about that subject =P

Comment: No issues at all....It was just an ADDITIONAL question ...You have answered the original question PERFECTLY...So I'll accept the answer ...Thx again..

Answer (score 1):

### Expanding with Overflow

> Boxes with an overflow value other than visible will expand vertically to enclose any floated descendant boxes

This property is useful when clearing floating elements.  A common problem is that a floated element doesn't get contained by its parent; using `overflow` is an easy way to solve this problem.

[Take a look at this sample](http://jsbin.com/olayih) where the `p` is floated from inside the `div` - the `div` doesn't expand to wrap it.  If we add `overflow:hidden` to the `div`, it expands vertically to contain its child.

[Here's the final result on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/agiwuj)

### Collapsing Margins

> Margins will never collapse for a box with an overflow value other than visible.

Let's take a look at the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapsing-margins) for more info (and examples) on collapsing margins:

> Certain adjoining margins combine to form a single margin. Those margins are said to “collapse.” Margins are adjoining if there are no nonempty content, padding or border areas or clearance to separate them.

The statement you included in your question means that this behavior can't be used when the `overflow` is set to `hidden`, `scroll`, or `auto`.